# How to validate user's input for English alphabet only in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Im experimenting  on a rails app . I would like to Validate user's input for English alphabet characters only in rails. Let's say we have a **sign up form** for user fill in their: **Name, Address, Email address**. But i would like them to fill the `Address form` with **English alphabet only**, Because  some of them might accidentally  fill in with Chinese alphabet which is not what we want.

Can we sort this out by a  **regular expression**  ? if so please guide me to write those three cases :  (Any other ways are very welcome)

1: validate "English alphabet only "

2: Validate "Chinese alphabet is not allowed "

Your help will be very much appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`validates_format_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of):

```
validates_format_of :address, :with => /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/
```

Comment: @Snailwalker Since you are validating an address, I'm assuming that you will be dealing with letters AND numbers. I recommend using this regular expression to validate strings: /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/

Comment: For RoR >= 4 regex will be /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `validates`  with `format`:

```
validates :address, format: { with: /[a-zA-Z0-9]/}
```